# lint-staged added path to command

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint, lint-staged

I have the following `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "npm run v2:lint",
    "v2:lint": "cd ./v2 && npm run lint && cd .."
},
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "*.{js, json}": "npm run lint"
}
```

However when I actually did a commit, I can see:

```
npm ERR! app@1.0.0 lint: `npm run v2:lint "C:/dev/codes/my-app/v2/app/index.js"`
```

As we can see, the file path is appended to the end but I didn't ask it to do so. Why is lint-staged do this?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, took me a while to realize. The whole idea of lint-staged is that you can use it to run linting or whatever commands you want **ONLY ON STAGED FILES**. So what it does is appends them to your command. Basically expect your commands to be run like this (example with prettier):

```
prettier --config .prettierrc --write {list of staged file paths}
```

So while usually you would add some path to the end like this

```
prettier --config .prettierrc --write ./src
```

Simply remove the path at the end and let the lint-staged provide the paths.

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.{js}": "prettier --config .prettierrc --write"
}
```